# Windows phone 8.1 SDK incoming call event

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, incoming-call

Is there any event to get incoming caller info in Windows phone 8.1 SDK? can we create application in windows phone 8.1 to get caller phone number while incoming call.

Answer (score 1):

Only available for OEMs. The little developer has no chance...

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Phone_call_SMS_filter_applications